# Java: remove all objects with iterator

Tags: java, foreach, while-loop, iterator

I am making a Library class that stores objects of a Class Book in an ArrayList colection. I have most of the functionality however I would like a remove function that deletes all objects of a parameter (name) when called. The function I have made so far seems only to delete the first element it encounters and then stops executing.

My Library Class looks like this (code to add objects omitted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Library {
    private ArrayList<Book> collection;
    private Book book;

public Library() {
    collection = new ArrayList<Book>();

}

public Book findBook(String searchBook) {

    Book bookB = null;
    Iterator<Book> it = collection.iterator();
    boolean found = false;

    while (it.hasNext() && !found) {
        bookB = it.next();
        String b = book.getBookName();

        if (b.equals(searchBook)) {
            found = true;

        }
    }

    if (found) {
        return bookB;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void removeBook (String searchBook) { 

    if (findBook(searchBook) != null && bookname.equals(searchBook)) {
        Book b = findBook(searchBook);
        System.out.println("Removed " + b.getBookName());
        collection.remove(b);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Don't worry, we don't have that one anyways");
    }
}
```

}

A friend of mine told me to make a foreach loop to wrap the if/else inside removeBook, but I have been unsuccessful doing that so far because honestly I do not know how to implement it.

Any help, insight, or feedback at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for [Iterator#remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) ?

Comment: Yes, I need to Iterate over all the objects in collection and then delete each object with same name(String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to iterate over all the elements of list and then check for book name that equals what you passed in as a parameter to removeBook method and if you find such an entry then remove it via iterator's remove method. So code should be something like:

```
Iterator<Book> it = collection.iterator();
Book book;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    book = it.next();
    if (book.getBookName().equals(searchBook)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
Book b = findBook(searchBook);
while(b != null) {
    collection.remove(b);
    b = findBook(searchBook);
    ...
 }
```

Comment: I tried the function and it compiles, but when I try to execute it returns java.langNullPointerException: null in String b = book.getBookName();

Comment: You're probably inserting null objects into the list somewhere. Since you always test it.hasNext() before doing book = it.next(), book will always be some element of the list. You could test if it is null before extracting its name, but that is not good, it would be best if you figured out where in your code null Books are being inserted into the list.

Answer (score 0):

The `while (it.hasNext() && !found)` in your `findBook(searchBook)` method stops once it has found the book with name passed as argument. And returns that `book`. That is why only one object with that `name` is deleted. Change your code to return a `list` of all objects with that name. Just check the return type `booksFound` if it has books in it like `booksFound.Size > 0`. And then iterate over the list and delete them.

```
public List<Book> findBook(String searchBook) {

Book bookB = null;
Iterator<Book> it = collection.iterator();
List<Book> booksFound = new ArrayList<Book>();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    bookB = it.next();
    String b = book.getBookName();

    if (b.equals(searchBook)) {
        booksFound.add(b);
    }
}
return booksFound;
}
```

And the remove method:

```
public void removeBook (String searchBook) { 

List<Books> booksFound = findBook(searchBook);
if(booksFound.size() > 0) {
   for (Book book: booksFound) {
      collection.remove(book);
   }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Don't worry, we don't have that one anyways");
}
}
```

Comment: Seems very complicated that I have to do this many changes to be able to apply such a (relatively) small functionality. I am a complete beginner at java and will of course listen to any advice given here, but shouldn't it be easier than this?

Note: I tried the solution of top comment and it worked very well. Is there any advantages to using a list like you describe over just regular object iteration?

Comment: In programming there is always balance between simplicity and flexibility of code. The above code may look longer or complicated but is very flexible if you have to make changes in the future. You can use `findBook(arg)` method for different tasks in your application. If you restrict this program to one specific task you will need to write another method. Hence you will end up writing same method over and over again which is redundant and will make code maintaince tough. Always think about future use of the program when coding. So that it is easy to extend the code and maintain it.